# Why am I getting this error (related to pip and easy_install) when trying to setup a virtualenv?

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv, pip, easy-install

I'm trying to create a Flask application to push to Heroku. When I try to create a virtualenv in the folder, I'm thrown this error:

```
photo-crawl › sudo virtualenv venv --distribute
Password:
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing distribute............................................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
Installing pip....
  Complete output from command /Users/evansiegel/In...rawl/venv/bin/python -x /Users/evansiegel/In...env/bin/easy_install /Library/Python/2.7/...ort/pip-1.2.1.tar.gz:
  /Users/evansiegel/Involvio/photo-crawl/venv/bin/python: can't open file '/Users/evansiegel/Involvio/photo-crawl/venv/bin/easy_install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
----------------------------------------
...Installing pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.8.4', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 964, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1076, in create_environment
    install_pip(py_executable, search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 667, in install_pip
    filter_stdout=_filter_setup)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1042, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/evansiegel/In...rawl/venv/bin/python -x /Users/evansiegel/In...env/bin/easy_install /Library/Python/2.7/...ort/pip-1.2.1.tar.gz failed with error code 2
```

It seems that for some reason `virtualenv` is not putting everything it should be putting into the `venv/bin` folder. Right now, only `python` and two aliases, `python2` and `python2.7` are in there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is caused by a bug in older versions of virtualenv and/or pip. It looks like you're using virtualenv 1.8.4 and pip 1.2.1. Is it possible for you to upgrade to latest virtualenv and pip (currently virtualenv 1.9.1 and pip 1.3.1)?

This should do it, if you have install privileges:

```
pip install pip --upgrade
pip install virtualenv --upgrade
```

At that point running the same command (i.e. `sudo virtualenv venv --distribute`) should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks this really helped. I was facing above issue on Ubuntu when trying to create virtualenv for python 3. Confusion was that it used a work a few months back. So, when I faced the issue, it got resolved after above updates. Thank again.